# How to fit an appropriate SDE

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, econometrics, finance

Does any one know how we can fit an appropriate SDE to a time series data? how to understand which model will describe the model well? and then how to estimate its parameters?
To be more specified, I am working on stock market data and I need to forecast and I am confused by using Fractional noise or Heston model or any other model.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: This is too broad to be answered here. You need to take a course on time series. Try to constrain yourself to a single, narrow, concrete question.

Comment: @gung I think there is a concrete question here: "how do I choose a method for fitting a SDE to time series data?" That said, the question would be more answerable if the user stated what they actually wanted to do with their data:  forecast prices? Model volatility? Etc.

Comment: @ssdecontrol I want to optimize a portfolio, so first of all I need to have a good model for our securities behavior that is why I would like to fit an appropriate SDE first, I had time series course before but we mostly studied ARMA and GARCH process which are not useful here, Our volatility graph shows smile behavior which motivated me to use Heston model, but I am not still sure if the Heston model is the best.

Comment: @gung thank you for answering me, actually I can't understand why my question is not concrete, please tell me how I can add more information about my problem. and I had course in time series before but unfortunately we have not discussed fitting SDE, if you know any good source to learn more about it please introduce it to me.